# Make rows in column same height as row parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't find how to fill column height with child content. I tried with bootstrap grid system and using flex utilities.

The only thing that worked is to set the row height to 50%, the problem is I don't know how many rows are in a column (it could be 1, 2 or 3 rows):

This is what I want:
[image: This is what I want]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .c1{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .c2{
                background-color: rgb(98, 0, 255);
            }
            .c3{
                background-color: rgb(101, 255, 160);
            }
            .c4{
                background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
            }
            .c5{
                background-color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
            }
            .c6{
                background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
            }
            .r0{
                background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);
            }
            .ra{
                background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
                height: 50%;
            }
            .rb{
                background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
                height: 50%;
            }
            .rc{
                background-color: rgb(255, 0, 191);
            }
            .rd{
                background-color: rgb(240, 255, 24);
            }
            .re{
                background-color: rgb(111, 133, 255);
            }
            .rf{
                background-color: rgb(180, 57, 57);
                height: 50%;
            }
            .rg{
                background-color: rgb(91, 206, 110);
                height: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container py-3">
        <div class="row r0">
            <div class="col c1">
                <div class="row ra">a</div>
                <div class="row rb">b</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col c2">2</div>
            <div class="col c3">3</div>
            <div class="col c4">
                <div class="row rc">c</div>
                <div class="row rd">d</div>
                <div class="row re">e</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col c5">
                <div class="row rf">f</div>
                <div class="row rg">g</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I tried:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .c1{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .c2{
                background-color: rgb(98, 0, 255);
            }
            .c3{
                background-color: rgb(101, 255, 160);
            }
            .c4{
                background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
            }
            .c5{
                background-color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
            }
            .c6{
                background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
            }
            .r0{
                background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);
            }
            .ra{
                background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
            }
            .rb{
                background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
            }
            .rc{
                background-color: rgb(255, 0, 191);
            }
            .rd{
                background-color: rgb(240, 255, 24);
            }
            .re{
                background-color: rgb(111, 133, 255);
            }
            .rf{
                background-color: rgb(180, 57, 57);
            }
            .rg{
                background-color: rgb(91, 206, 110);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container py-3">
        <div class="row r0">
            <div class="col c1">
                <div class="row ra">a</div>
                <div class="row rb">b</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col c2">2</div>
            <div class="col c3">3</div>
            <div class="col c4">
                <div class="row rc">c</div>
                <div class="row rd">d</div>
                <div class="row re">e</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col c5">
                <div class="row rf">f</div>
                <div class="row rg">g</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result is
[image: that]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use bootstraps' grid system for this. It isn't a grid you're trying to  achieve.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Do not use the above - this is just for display purposes */

.my-container>.flex-column {
  width: 100px; /* Width of each column */
}

.my-container>.flex-column>div {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}

.c1 {
  a background-color: red;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: rgb(98, 0, 255);
}

.c3 {
  background-color: rgb(101, 255, 160);
}

.c4 {
  background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
}

.c5 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 242);
}

.c6 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
}

.r0 {
  background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);
}

.ra {
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
}

.rb {
  background-color: rgb(72, 255, 0);
}

.rc {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 191);
}

.rd {
  background-color: rgb(240, 255, 24);
}

.re {
  background-color: rgb(111, 133, 255);
}

.rf {
  background-color: rgb(180, 57, 57);
}

.rg {
  background-color: rgb(91, 206, 110);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex py-3 my-container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="ra">a</div>
      <div class="rb">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="c2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="c3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="rc">c</div>
      <div class="rd">d</div>
      <div class="re">e</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="rf">f</div>
      <div class="rg">g</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```